# saving computed values in a file or table from a foreach loop in a regression plot

Tags: pgfplotstable, foreach

I want to save the regression slopes of those data sets for a further table.
I manage to add rows in a initial table in the foreach loop but adding the plots doesn't work anymore....
Thanks in advance for the advices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

% data
\pgfplotstableread{
x   y1  y2  y3
0   0.00    0.00    0.00
1   0.15    0.24    0.42
2   0.24    0.57    0.74
3   0.34    0.79    1.22
}\data

% slope data header
\pgfplotstableread{
    N   slope
}\slopedata


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

%loop
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,3}{
    \addplot+[only marks]
        table [x=x,y index=#1]
        {\data};
    \addplot[no marks]
        table [x=x,y={create col/linear regression={y=[index]#1}}]
        {\data};
    \edef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
    % append new slope to slopedata
    \pgfplotstableread[header=has colnames,col sep=comma,row sep=crcr]{
        N,slope\\
        #1,\slope\\
    }\mynewrow
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\slopedata}{\mynewrow}
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Output
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\slopedata}

\end{document}
```